# (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str ) im just doing a backtest with the help of SMA and im getting these error

Tags: python

here is my some part of  code

```
symbol_list ={3456:'TATAMOTORS-EQ'}
while True:
    for name in symbol_list:
        df= api.get_time_price_series(exchange='NSE', token='3456', starttime=57.1634209, 
        endtime=1644690600.0, interval=5)
        df["sma5"]=ta.SMA(df["intc"],timeperiod=5)
        print(df)
```

outpute:

```
runfile('C:/Users/ADITYA/Downloads/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/ADITYA/Downloads')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ADITYA\Downloads\untitled1.py", line 33, in <module>
    df["sma5"]=ta.SMA(df["intc"],timeperiod=5)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: can you `print(df)`, and show the output ?

Comment: yes i can print df successfully

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs due to some reasons, as follows

1. Your data frame (df) column value is a string type, and **ta.SMA()**
   required int and float types values.
2. Maybe your data frame columns have object types. some values are
   str type. So you need to convert your data frame into the proper
   input format.

The second solution to your problem is as follows code snippet

```
symbol_list ={3456:'TATAMOTORS-EQ'}
while True:
    for name in symbol_list:
        try:
            df= api.get_time_price_series(exchange='NSE', token='3456', starttime=57.1634209, 
            endtime=1644690600.0, interval=5)
            df["sma5"]=ta.SMA(df["intc"],timeperiod=5)
            print(df)
        except:
           pass
```

Comment: I use your code  but now I'm not getting output